# Select objects by index of array in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to select a collection of objects using ActiveRecord by the index in the array.

I know I can select Item.first or Item.last or single or range.  But I want to update an arbitrary group by the index of their position in the array.

```
collection = Item.all.to_a
collection[3,5,9,11]
```

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance...

-- edit --

Thanks to tokland's help, I was able to get it to work perfect.

In case anyone else wants to do something similar, here is what I did:

```
yesterday = Time.now - 1.day
i = Item.all
new_items = i.values_at(1,3,5,10,11,14,18)
new_items.each{ |e| e.update_attributes(:published_at => yesterday) }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean indexes in an array (not IDs):

```
collection.values_at(3, 5, 9, 11)
```

Comment: Thanks tokland, This does work!  I'm trying to update attributes on a collection for testing.  is this the best way to get at it?

Comment: Actually, I believe I can't update attributes on an array.  I think I need to do an each.  I'll keep working at it.  Thanks again tokland!

Comment: Thanks tokland.  I got it working, and provided the code in my edit above...  (hopefully that was the right place to do so)

Answer (score 1):

If i properly understand, you need

```
Item.find([3,5,9,11])
```

This is how you can find a record given an id. But it method throws an exception if there would be some id that doesn't exist.

```
Item.find_all_by_id([3,5,9,11])
```

That will work even if some of the ids don't exist.

Comment: Thanks WarHog, but I'm trying to avoid using ID's as this is for a test db, and they will be constantly changing...

Comment: Aha, got it, sorry for my misunderstanding.. Then @tokland approach should help you.